# react native listview won't scroll

Tags: android, listview, react-native

I'm just learning react-native, and I have multiple issues with listview scrolling.  Using the sample code below, on my android emulator, it won't scroll at all.  Pasting the code into React-native playground (https://rnplay.org/apps/AXOzjw) and testing it on the iOS emulator there, if i pull down on it, it scrolls back to the top when i'm done.

I've read through a few SO answers, and most talk about not having flex:1 set on the containers, but i'm pretty sure i have that set properly.

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  Image,
  ListView,
  TouchableHighlight,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    title: '<ListView> - Simple',
    description: 'Performant, scrollable list of data.'
  },
  getInitialState: function() {
      var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      var data = Object.keys(scores.games).map(function(k) { return scores.games[k] });
      return {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(data),
      };
    },

    render: function() {
      return (
        <View style = {styles.maincontainer}>
          <ListView contentContainerStyle={styles.list}
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={this._renderRow}  />
        </View>
      );
    },

  _renderRow: function(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
      return (
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.item}>
              {rowData.name}
            </Text>
          </View> );
    },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    maincontainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop:20,
    paddingBottom:10,
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  list: 
  {
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flex:1,
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    margin: 3,
    flex:1,
    height: 60
  }
});

var scores = {
  "games": [{
    "name": "1",
  }, {
    "name": "2",
  }, {
    "name": "3",
  }, {
    "name": "4",
  }, {
    "name": "5",
  }, {
    "name": "6",
  }, {
    "name": "7 ",
  }, {
    "name": "8 ",
  }, {
    "name": "9",
  }, {
    "name": "10",
  }, {
    "name": "11",
  }, {
    "name": "12",
  }, {
    "name": "13",
  }]
};

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);

module.exports = SampleApp;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
contentContainerStyle={ styles.list }
```

Just use:

```
style={ styles.list }
```

Got it working [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/KQegVQ).

Comment: Thank you! That was driving me insane.  I'll accept the answer as soon as SO allows.

Comment: @NaderDabit ur link is broken, could u post a repo or a gist with the solution?