# ListView won't scroll to bottom

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I create some listview application, I add listview in my view.
I can't scroll to bottom.

[image]

I found same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34934030/react-native-listview-wont-scroll).
I think it is similar problem but I didn't find solution.

this is [gist](https://gist.github.com/ChangJoo-Park/85944fbe24baa41278cd).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `height` of the `ListView`.

To set it to the height of your screen, just do the following :

```
var {..., Dimensions, ...} = React;

var screenHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height
```

Then set `height: screenHeight` in your `ScrollView` style

Comment: Helped me too! Keep in mind if you have a custom header (supplied by `react-navigation/native`) you need to subtract it's height.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't scroll, is because it has no height defined.
You can check this using the inspector via the dev-menu.

You can fix it by setting a height using the `height` style, or just by using `flex: 1` somewhere in your ListView's style.

Using `flex: 1` makes a component fill out all remaining space. So it'd make your ListView calculate its height accordingly.

If it still doesn't work, check whether or not all of its parents have a defined height (once again either with the `height` or `flex` property)

Comment: Agree, `flex: 1` seems to be more flexible.